# add default namespaces

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

Is it possible to somehow add default namespaces to each code file that I am editing in Visual Studio 2010 web site project? I am tired of specifying them each time I edit a page because they are pretty much the same on each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add namespaces in `web.config`, in the `<pages>` section in order to not have to include them in every page.

You add them like this:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>        
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, I use Resharper since five years or so which means that is a problem that has disappeared from my world. Get Resharper and join the alt-enter world.

Answer (score 0):

There are no namespaces in Web site projects. If you want that, you have to use the Web Project template.